# Why calling JOIN after we already found data from inner SELECT?

Tags: mysql, database, join

in the SQL statement below, why do we have to use this last JOIN on `total_sellers_month`?

```
SELECT 
    best.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        rm.rc_year,
        rm.rc_month,
        (SELECT vm.vd_id 
            FROM total_sellers_month vm 
            WHERE vm.rc_year = rm.rc_year AND vm.rc_month = rm.rc_month 
            ORDER BY rc_total DESC LIMIT 1
        ) AS vd_id
        FROM total_months rm
    ) AS best
    JOIN sellers v ON (v.vd_id = best.vd_id)
    JOIN total_sellers_month rm 
        ON (rm.vd_id = best.vd_id AND rm.rc_year = best.rc_year AND rm.rc_month = best.rc_month )
ORDER BY rc_year, rc_month;
```

We have the second SELECT that already gives us the year, month, and id depending on the best months/years :

```
    (SELECT 
        rm.rc_year,
        rm.rc_month,
        (SELECT vm.vd_id 
            FROM total_sellers_month vm 
            WHERE vm.rc_year = rm.rc_year AND vm.rc_month = rm.rc_month 
            ORDER BY rc_total DESC LIMIT 1
        ) AS vd_id
        FROM total_months rm
    ) AS best
```

Then we add the sellers to have some more informations (the name of each seller, etc.), and the we repeat the call to `total_sellers_month` with a Join :

```
JOIN total_sellers_month rm 
        ON (rm.vd_id = best.vd_id AND rm.rc_year = best.rc_year AND
```

Why don't we just use a JOIN on "sellers"? The data we retrieved from the inner SELECT is not enough to be recognized as a table for the join?

Comment: is that query modified for this question at all? in particular `best.*` : is that really the only source of output columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you would only join from `best` onto `total_sellers_month` to get columns you did not gather from the derived table. This can be a valid technique where `best` is simply the way to locate the rows that you need, but then must join back to the source table for access to those complete source rows.

However as you are displaying only "select best.*" in the question there isn't a purpose to any of the joins. Perhaps this may be due to simplification for the question.

Comment: Yes I simplified it for the question. So, `best` is not a table with the result we want? Edit: ok I think I understood what you mean, we would want the whole line, But, the whole line is already "id, year, month" so we don't add more informations in the JOIN.

Comment: If you need columns from total_sellers_month in the topmost select list that are not present in then `best` subquery, then, yes you need that join.